# Start and verify Dart VM service

Tags: dart

I have a two part question.

First, what Dart command should I use to "start"
the VM service listening for requests, with possibly
giving it what host and port number to use.

I'm using Windows, and I don't need the Observatory possibly
interfering.

I'm currently trying to use this, after I CD into the project's directory:

```
dart --pause_isolates_on_start bicycle
```

And the second part of the question is, is it possible to verify
that the VM service is there and listening on whatever port?

I want to be able to send a request to the VM service,
from a WebSocket client, and get back a response.

After I give the above command, if I do a 'netstat'
it doesn't look like there is anything there listening.

And any attempts at trying to connect to the VM service get
a connection refused Exception, same as if I didn't even
try to start the VM service.

UPDATE:

I was looking at the intelliJ plugin code, to see how they did their connect,
and saw that they used "ws://localhost:8181/ws", I was trying to use
"ws://localhost:8181", and now it's finally getting past the handshake,
the server was returning "200 OK" instead of "101" before.

I'm assuming that I'm talking to the Observer at this point,
and not the VM service, I'm not sure, but at least I'm further along..

When it worked, I was using:

dart --enable-vm-service --pause_isolates_on_start bicycle.dart

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

`dart --help -v` prints

```
--observe[=<port>[/<bind-address>]]
  The observe flag is a convenience flag used to run a program with a
  set of options which are often useful for debugging under Observatory.
  These options are currently:
      --enable-vm-service[=<port>[/<bind-address>]]
      --pause-isolates-on-exit
      --pause-isolates-on-unhandled-exceptions
      --warn-on-pause-with-no-debugger
  This set is subject to change.
  Please see these options for further documentation.
```

It depends on what exactly you want to do, but as far as I know the Observatory just uses this service and if you don't access any of its features, it won't add additional load to the process.

There is a Dart client API https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/vm_service_client and a documentation about the protocol https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/vm/service/service.md

Perhaps this is what you are looking for

```
enum EventKind {
  // Notification that VM identifying information has changed. Currently used
  // to notify of changes to the VM debugging name via setVMName.
  VMUpdate,

  // Notification that a new isolate has started.
  IsolateStart,
```

used with Events https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/vm/service/service.md#events

Comment: I've looked at 'dart -v'.  I want to interact with the
Dart VM service directly, and not the Observatory.  Using '--observe'
and '--enable-vm-service' all respond with 'Observatory listening on [host/port]' and I don't want that.

Comment: Even though it says Observatory is listening on ..
I found that I can connect to the default host and port
at that point, so I'm going to try to send a 'getVersion' request and see what I get back.

Comment: I'm having an issue with the server not doing the
'Connection: Upgrade'.  With ws://echo.websocket.org I get back 'HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake', but with the server it gets back 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
This is directly from the WebSocket implementation I'm using
and the firewall off.  Using ws://127.0.0.1:8181

Comment: Are you building the client in Dart or some other language?

Comment: The client and WebSocket code are all in Java.  I could manually tweak what gets sent if needed.  I've looked at some of the same issues in the Dart SDK, but this is directly from the WebSocket code.

Comment: This is what is getting sent:   (Full)bui: 'GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:8181
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ueoRIzZm1qNqGabxkY6m3A==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket

'  Same, but in this case I'm using 'localhost'

Comment: "Observer at this point, and not the VM service" I think observe and VM service are the same. What you don't want is the Observatory.